# Only Display Woocommerce Side Bar on some pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, hook, woocommerce

Im trying to get the side bar layout on the pages for some categories but not others, I have tried editing the page template in wordpress but of course its hard coded into woocommerce. Is there a way I can write an `if` statement around the

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

which is in `archive-product.php` to not show this code for category a and b, or will this not work as it is `@hooked` ?

Comment: Which (if any) theme are you using for your store?

Comment: The Retailer, I have tweeked one or two things on it but nothing to do with the side bar other than a little css.